# Android AlarmManager repeat only one time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to work with `AlarmManager` and service to send auto SMS to some number. I followed some tutorials and I wrote something like this:

```
        SwitchPreference testPref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("key_auto_sms");
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("XXXXXXXXX", MODE_PRIVATE);
        testPref.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("AutoSMS", false));

        testPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (testPref.isChecked()) {

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    // Checking whether current hour is over 14
                    if (curHr >= 15)
                    {
                        // Since current hour is over 15, setting the date to the next day
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    }


                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("XXXXXXXXX", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("AutoSMS", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.Auto_SMS_Enable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.camel.work_list", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("AutoSMS", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.Auto_SMS_Cancle), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    //getActivity().stopService(intent1);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**My BroadcastReceiver:**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // MY auto sms method.....
      }
    }
```

So the problem is that the alarm will work only one time and then the day after that it stops.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

You should not use setRepeating() because it's not accurate at time intervals. You can use the set() function at a time, it will work more accurately, when the broadcast is called you can call set() again (like recursive), it will work.
This is my alarm set code, It will not work with some devices like huawei because the processes will be killed. With huawei I use JobScheduler. It works fine in case the screen is bright when the screen is off. It does not work correctly. Recently there is a WorkManager library that works better for all devices, I have not had the time to research it, so I do not give any advice on the WorkManager library. Hope it helps

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            assert alarmManager != null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, pendingIntent), pendingIntent);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
            }
```

Comment: I will try your method, But another question, Maybe you suggest to use some library from Github?

Comment: link documentation documentation from google: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
if you want lib github, it's here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager
Note, I have not used or followed so I do not guarantee it will work well.

Comment: Hey bro, I really really need your help, it doesn't work.
I was try to do it in recursive with only "set()" and it work ones and that's it, But if i put in on setRepeating it's works for 3 days and after that nothing :(... What is wrong?

Comment: I do not understand, can you post code to github and i can help, as i also recently worked with alarmmanager recently

Comment: I upload part of the code: 
https://gist.github.com/sharon2469/7c517657afb4c1c8d368e3d56e6257fb

Comment: OMG bro I think that i found the problem... look at Opiatefuchs answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328244/alarmmanager-not-working-properly

Comment: I see a small problem in your code, since you use the add() function and then use the set() function for Calendar, I think that's the problem it does not repeat. You must call the add function after using the set() function to work

Comment: And please use my statement above for different API versions instead of just using alarm.set ().

Comment: Hey bro, it's works perfect :)
But now i faced with another issue, The: ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
And The: ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS

I do some research and i found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114063/how-do-i-properly-fire-action-request-ignore-battery-optimizations-intent/33114136

If my app is send AUTO SMS in specific time every 24 hours do i allowed to add this permission ?

Comment: I don't know, I have never used this permission.